# Fast method for scrolling looping backgrounds in javascript?

Tags: javascript, performance

Do you know a fast method for scrolling looping backgrounds in javascript ?
[image]

I use fillRect with a pattern, like :

```
x += 2 ; if( x >= pattern_width ){ x -= pattern_width ; }
y += 1.5 ; if( y >= pattern_height ){ y -= pattern_height ; }
ctx.fillStyle = background_pattern ;
ctx.fillRect( -pattern_width+x , -pattern_height+y , game_width , game_height );
```

The problem is that fillRect is very slow, it alone takes 24% in the profiler though it is called only once per frame, that is huge.
I tried calling drawImage() in a for loop instead but it is about as slow.

(update) I tried filling an invisible canvas with the pattern then just drawing it, calling drawImage() only once for that canvas instead of many times for tiles, but that is quite similar : 22%.

(update) Instead of drawing on the canvas, I did set the tile as the css background of the canvas and I just animated .style.backgroundPosition. According to the profiler it seems faster : 9%, but it lags more, that is strange. (Well, this computer is old, there may be no css hardware acceleration.)

Do you know a fast method ?

Comment: Is it always a checkered tile? If it's a simple pattern like a checkered tile then there's a cheat

Comment: Yes, they are, except I add a little drawing inside the squares instead of leaving them solid color, so they are 4x4 squares tiles, not 2x2 like real checkered tiles would be. But I am interested in learning about your trick anyway, even if it only works with solid color checkered tiles.

Comment: A simple solution might be to render a single canvas at 2 times the size you need and then move the view point from the top left to the bottom right and then reset.

Comment: Do you need to use canvas?

Comment: @Quirliom : Moving a bigger canvas instead of redrawing ? That is interesting, I'll try, thanks. By the way it only needs to be screen size + tile size, not two times bigger.

Comment: @Aaron : Actually, no. But I need it to be able to scale with css along with the game canvas.

Comment: 24% of *what*? If you show that static screen, there's no much else happening, the other 76% would be drawing the three strings?

Comment: Sure, 24% of an empty scene would be nothing, but that screen lags a little on both my computer and my tablet, 24% of a slow screen is big. (I do not remember how to tell how long in ms does a function take per frame, I will search and tell) There are ~20 sweets falling down, they use rotation and scaling so I was expecting them to be 'expensive'. Title and buttons are sprites slowly waving. Everything else is so insignificant that it doesn't even appear in the profiler. I only have idle (empty) program (68-75%) and my main loop (25-31%) with only the rendering inside.